# How to set/change creator of document in alfresco in webscript

Tags: alfresco

How can I change 'creator' property in webscript in Alfresco of uploaded document?

I am using Alfresco 4.2, btw.

Best,
D

Comment: Javascript or Java webscript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm not wrong ***cm:creator***, ***cm:modifier***, ***cm:created***, ***cm:modified***, etc...are auditable properties in Alfresco it means, can't be updated manually because are managed by Alfresco.

I have developed a java backed webscript and I have added this code (to update the creator and modifier properties) that is working properly:

```
// Disable auditable aspect to allow change properties of cm:auditable aspect
policyBehaviourFilter.disableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);

// Update properties of cm:auditable aspect
nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CREATOR, "xxxxxx");
nodeService.setProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_MODIFIER, "xxxxxx");

// Enable auditable aspect
policyBehaviourFilter.enableBehaviour(nodeRef, ContentModel.ASPECT_AUDITABLE);
```

Don't forget to add in your context.xml file where you declare your beans:

```
<bean id="xxxxxxxx" 
      class="your class package"
  parent="webscript">
  <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService" />
  ........
      <property name="policyBehaviourFilter" ref="policyBehaviourFilter" />     
</bean>
```

Good luck

Comment: Your answer should contain the actual answer, not a link to the answer. If the blog goes down in the future, your 'answer' would be lost!

Comment: Thank you for answer. 
I tested on a 4.1 edition and the solution didn't work as such for me . I needed to override with a manual transaction like this:

`UserTransaction tx = transactionService.getUserTransaction();
tx.begin();
... code in example above
tx.commit();`

Answer (score 4):

The "cm:creator" is a controlled audited property that cannot be changed directly. Much like "cm:modifier" which is updated by the system when a user authority modifies the content/properties (content is just a special property really) of the document node.

You can change the owner of a document via the Repository APIs. This is a permissions change though and will still not change the cm:creator property (and it shouldn't).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [this forum post](https://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=18739).

Like stated, after the field is set it can't be changed any more. You could or change the contentModel.xml to set the cm:creator field to default (which is read and write).

Or you could copy the document on the moment and set the FullyAuthenticatedUser for a short time and revert it afterwards. You will need to write some Java Code for it (e.g. in a Java Action).